# If user is admin disable the maintenance, if user is normal enable the maintenance

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm making a DJ panel for DJ's (oh really). Sometimes the technical crew wants to update the website, so there needs to be an "maintenance script" to disable the whole website.

```
// The website is connected to DB and session is running

// if maintenance is enabled, throw the maintenance page in there and exit everything else
if($maintenance) {include("inc/maintenance.php");exit();}

// fetch the db info for the maintenance script
$statussen1 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM status3 WHERE naam='onderhoud'");
$statussen  = mysqli_fetch_array($statussen1);

// check if 'maintenance' row in the DB is set to AAN (means ON in Dutch)
if(htmlentities($statussen['status']) == 'AAN') {

// if maintenance is AAN, check if the user is an staff member
if(htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '1' // owner
OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '2' // head dj
OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '3' // assistant head dj
OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '4' // pilot dj
OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '5' // test dj
OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '6' // something else, not sure what 6 is called :P
OR htmlentities($gegevens['nieuwsreporter']) == '1'
OR htmlentities($gegevens['moderator']) == '1') {
    // disable the maintenance script if staff
    $maintenance = false;
} else {
    // or if the user is no staff, enable the maintenance script
    $maintenance = true;
}
}
```

I think I've done a good job trying to explain in the script what it all is so ya'll understand it a bit better. However, the script gives me a blank page when the maintenance in the DB is set to AAN.

I've checked the script like 100 times but can't find anything related to a problem. Yeah, I've set error reporting to `E_ALL` and only gives me this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: maintenance in
>   xxx on line 7

Line 7 is

```
if($maintenance) {include("inc/maintenance.php");exit();}
```

But that shouldn't be the REAL problem causing the blank page. I must have done something wrong somewhere. Please help me out.

Comment: It looks like you are using $maintenance before you are setting it.

Comment: @Cayde6 Hey Cayde, I've edited my code but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Can you please identify line #7 for us? As far as I can tell, line #7 has a comment and PHP would have to be broken beyond fubar for that to be occurring. Thanks.

Comment: What is line 7? You must be using $maintenance before the parts shown.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Why isn't Stack supporting line numbers.. Do you mean this line: `if(htmlentities($statussen['status']) == 'AAN') {`

Comment: @Carl You need to post the code from the the file which contains the error.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ah, right. I will do that! Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `if($maintenance) {include("inc/maintenance.php");exit();}` this is the code for line 7.

Comment: @Carl Do you need assistance in understanding Cayde 6's comment?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Well, I am trying to figure it out myself but it isn't working out. Line 7 isn't causing the issue, I assume?

Comment: This could help: [isset](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php). It validates that the variable exist and that is not "NULL".
Because if it is not declared before `if(htmlentities($statussen['status']) == 'AAN')` and that condition isn't true it will reach `if($maintenance) {include("inc/maintenance.php");exit();}` without being declared.

Comment: @Carl Line #7 **is** the issue because the the PHP compiler says so. There really is no further argument.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Might have skipped the lesson in class about this. Sorry for the confusion here!

Comment: @Carl No sweat, just keep in mind that if someone is requesting for clarification to your code then they are doing so because they are trying to figure out which of the 20 different causes of your error you have triggered. Good luck in class.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That is true, I'm learning more from SO than from class to be honest! Thanks for your input on my issue and have a nice day, sir.

Comment: Is that code included from other script? As you test for `$maintenance` at line 7, before testing for AAN in the following lines, if it isn't being included, them it's undefined at line 7. Please add to your answer the "inc/maintenance.php" file. If that file is being included and it isn't outputting something, then with the exit after the include, it's a reason for a blank output. As a side note, I recommend for the search for "psr-2", which is an excellent guidance for formatting PHP code. Like you have it might not be that easy to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line 7 to

```
if( isset($maintenance) ) {include("inc/maintenance.php");exit();}
```

and then edit the rest of your code so it looks like this:

```
// The website is connected to DB and session is running


// you can't use maintenance up here, php knows nothing about this variable.
// it needs to be set before you can use it

// fetch the db info for the maintenance script
$statussen1 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM status3 WHERE naam='onderhoud'");
$statussen  = mysqli_fetch_array($statussen1);

// check if 'maintenance' row in the DB is set to AAN (means ON in Dutch)
if(htmlentities($statussen['status']) == 'AAN') {

    // if maintenance is AAN, check if the user is an staff member
    if(htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '1' // owner
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '2' // head dj
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '3' // assistant head dj
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '4' // pilot dj
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '5' // test dj
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '6' // something else, not sure what 6 is called :P
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['nieuwsreporter']) == '1'
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['moderator']) == '1') {
        // disable the maintenance script if staff
        $maintenance = false;
    } else {
        // or if the user is no staff, enable the maintenance script
        $maintenance = true;
        // if maintenance is enabled, throw the maintenance page in there and exit everything else
        include("inc/maintenance.php");exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed the issue. I thought it was a much bigger issue with my code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for the value of `$maintenance` before it's set. Move it down past the `else`.

```
// fetch the db info for the maintenance script
$statussen1 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM status3 WHERE naam='onderhoud'");
$statussen  = mysqli_fetch_array($statussen1);

// check if 'maintenance' row in the DB is set to AAN (means ON in Dutch)
if(htmlentities($statussen['status']) == 'AAN') {

    // if maintenance is AAN, check if the user is an staff member
    if(htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '1' // owner
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '2' // head dj
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '3' // assistant head dj
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '4' // pilot dj
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '5' // test dj
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '6' // something else, not sure what 6 is called :P
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['nieuwsreporter']) == '1'
    OR htmlentities($gegevens['moderator']) == '1') {
        // disable the maintenance script if staff
        $maintenance = false;
    } else {
        // or if the user is no staff, enable the maintenance script
        $maintenance = true;
    }
    // if maintenance is enabled, throw the maintenance page in there and exit everything else
    if($maintenance) {
        include("inc/maintenance.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I have solved the issue. I have play a fair game and mark bmcculley as accepted answer, he was 40 seconds faster than you. I'm sorry but I do wish you a nice day!